# Use Jenkins TFS-plugin from within TFS?

Tags: java, tfs, jenkins

Is there a possibility to use TFS as the main system and to start the [TFS-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) for Jenkins from within TFS itself and to push the (code quality) results from Jenkins through to TFS? In that way, you could push a button in TFS to start a Jenkins build with for example Sonar and see the results of that build also in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is a supported integration for sonar cube using Team Build (the TFS build environment) so one could use that if sonar cube is your goal; http://www.sonarqube.org/announcing-sonarqube-integration-with-msbuild-and-team-build/. But if you realy need to trigger jenkins, there are a lot of options to do that; [Triggering Jenkins after TFS build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731683/triggering-jenkins-after-tfs-build)