# Triggering Jenkins after TFS build

Tags: selenium, tfs, jenkins

I was wondering if it is possible for Jenkins to be notified after TFS finishes a build.

I'm trying to make a system where, after the TFS build, Jenkins is used to run automated selenium tests.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options:

1. You could use a [GenericTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286732.aspx) to trigger Jenkins and [include as part of the Build Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Run). This also allows your script to communicate pass/fail information back to the build.
2. You could just include an `InvokeProcess` workflow activity to trigger Jenkins. [The process would be similar to this](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/07/enabling-resharper-cli-in-team-build.html) or [this](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/part-14-execute-a-powershell-script.aspx).
3. Or you could use a tool that would trigger after a Team Build has finished. Normally people would use tools that then deploy stuff. Most of these tools trigger a Powershell script at some point, which would allow you to trigger the test run:

   - [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/blog/using-octopus-and-tfs-builds)
   - [TFS Deployer](http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/)