# Is there an equivalent for GitHub Organization plugin for Jenkins but for TFS-Git?

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs

Is there an equivalent for GitHub Organization plugin for Jenkins but for TFS-Git?

I have the team foundation server plugin but I can't find how to create a TFS organization job style...

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such concept of organization  in TFS. So you could also not use [Team Foundation Server plugin for Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md) to create a TFS organization job style.

---

**Update**

You can trigger a Jenkins build when you push code to your team project's Git repository or when you check code in to Team Foundation version control.

> 1. If you're setting
>      up Jenkins on-premises, enable HTTPS.
> 2. In Jenkins, create a new item. Create the type of build that's
>      appropriate for your project.
> 3. Set the URL for your Git repository in Visual Studio Team Services/TFS.
>      The URL is in the form `https://{VSTS
>      account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/{team project}`.
> 4. Go to your team project's administration page. On the **Service Hooks**
>          tab, create a subscription. Add Jenkins.
> 5. Pick the event from Visual Studio Team Services/TFS that you want to
>          trigger a Jenkins build.
> 6. Configure the action to take in Jenkins. Now, when that event occurs
>          in Visual Studio Team Services/TFS, your Jenkins build will be
>          triggered.

For more details please refer this tutorial: [Jenkins with Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/jenkins)

Comment: So how can I achieve automatic job triggering upon commit or pull request?

Comment: @ItaiGanot I'm not sure if you are meaning trigger Jenkins from TFS. You could use service hooks. Details please take a look the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971227/how-to-trigger-jenkins-build-when-changes-are-commited-to-tfs

Comment: Thanks! the answer in the SO question you provided solves my issue, please edit your answer to include it.