# Team foundation server not allowing the password from jenkins TFS plugin

Tags: jenkins, plugins, tfs

I have automated the job with groovy code. The password field in the TFS plugin gets the data and when we build the job it will not connect to the TFS server but when i enter the password manually in the job created then it is connecting the TFS server. How can i build the job as soon as it is created. Thanks in advance for your help. I have included the error snapshot below:

[image]

Comment: Based on the error message it's authentication issue. How did you set for the `[Job configuration](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#job-configuration)`? Credentials `Automatic`? Please check if this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971227/how-to-trigger-jenkins-build-when-changes-are-commited-to-tfs

Comment: The credentials are manual with username and password